# ExtJs 4 Data associations

Tags: extjs

I'm having a hard time getting what I want out of Ext. I'm trying to divide up a RESTful response with nested parameters. One of the parameters is an array of objects, where each object has a few more parameters. How can I build up the model/store/view to recognize this type of response?

```
response = {
  stuffINeed: {
    animals,
    fruits,
    veggies = {
      cucumbers,
      apples,
      pears,
      squash = {
        winter,
        pumpkin,
        summer = {
          yellow,
          green
        }
      }
    }
  },

  stuffIDontNeed: {
    ...
  },

  moreStuffIDontNeed: {
    ...
  }
}
```

How do I use associations to build up my model/store? Lets assume the 'base' model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.StuffINeed', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
      {name: 'animals', type: 'boolean'},
      {name: 'fruits', type: 'boolean'},
      {name: 'veggies', type: 'array'}
    ],

    hasMany: [{name: 'veggies', model: 'veggieModel'}],

    proxy: {
      type: 'REST',
      url: '/someserver'
      reader: {
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
      }
    }
  }
```

Do I need a second veggie model that mirrors the parameters I'm looking for? How do I inject an array of veggie models into my root?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Veggie', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    {name: 'cucumbers'},
    {name: 'apples'},
    {name: 'pears'},
    {name: 'squash', type: 'array'}

    belongsTo: 'MyApp.model.StuffINeed'
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you don't need the full integrity of the Model system, is to just use `type: 'auto'`, which keeps the data as the raw data returned.  Your `model.get('veggies')` will then give you an object that you can access like a normal javascript object.

Comment: That would be nice, but about 20 other properties exist already in the Model I'm editing. I can't refactor that way.